# How to control Media Volume when a Bluetooth device is connected?

Tags: android, bluetooth, volume

I have setted the StreamControlVolume in the OnCreate of my Activity in order to control Music/Media with volume buttons.

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

But when I connect a Bluetooth device to my application and Sco is routed, the VolumeControlStream switches to bluetooth, I have tried to change the VolumeControlStream after the Sco is on, but it still changes Bluetooth volume when I press the volume buttons like in the image below:

[image: Bluetooth volume changing]

I have tried to setControlStream right before the volume changes (overriding dispatchKeyEvent) but it didn't worked

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```